# Авто проверка последней версии pip

Tags: python, c++, cmd, pip

Я бы хотел чтобы программа проверяла последнюю существующую версию pip, сравнивала её с той, что установлена, и в случае если на пк старая версия - она обновлялась. Установленную версию даёт команда `pip --version`, а какая команда даст последнюю выпущенную версию pip? И сработает ли код на c++:

```
if (v!=v_new){
    system("python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip");
    system("python.exe -m easy_install pip");
}
```

Где v - значение, возвращённое `pip --version`,а n_new - последняя выпущенная версия.

Comment: В чём проблема просто всегда использовать `pip install -U pip`? `pip` проверит последнюю версию и установит, если это необходимо.

Comment: Спасибо, я думал что он всегда будет устанавливать по новой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно использовать `pip install -U pip`.

Если текущая версия является последней, то повторной установки не произойдёт:

```py
C:\Users\Username>pip install -U pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (20.1)
```